Difference between Gitlab runner scopes
I am trying to call gitlab api to get runner list. But I am bit confused in the scopes given in the documentation.
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN:${KEY}" "https://<git-url>/api/v4/projects/<pid>/runners?scope=active&status=online

Can some one please help me to understand the difference between "active" & "online" scope of the runner?
And same values are available in runner status as well. Are those status are having same meaning?
Gitlab API Reference link : Gitlab API

As the scope parameter is deprecated, its not really relevant.  You should be using the status and paused parameters instead.
I can't find really clear documentation on the old statuses, but based on this closed issue ticket:

Offline = Has not contacted GitLab in 2+ hours
Online = Has contacted GitLab within 2 hours.
Stale = offline for > 3 months or it has never contacted GitLab

Active seems to be independent of Online/Offline and also the opposite status of Paused, and the newer versions of the API reflect that.
Based on the documentation you linked above, the scope parameter is deprecated, and shouldn't be used anyway:

scope

Deprecated: Use type or status instead. The scope of runners to return, one of: active, paused, online and offline; showing all runners if none provided


Looking at status, it states that the active and paused statuses were part of this parameter but have been deprecated and moved to a separate boolean parameter:

status

The status of runners to return, one of: online, offline, stale, and never_contacted. active and paused are also possible values which were deprecated and will be removed in a future version of the REST API


There is this additional note below the table:

The active and paused values in the status query parameter were deprecated and will be removed in a future version of the REST API. They are replaced by the paused query parameter.

The active and paused values were deprecated in version 14.8 and were supposed to be removed in 16.0 according to the older documentation, so they aren't relevant unless your GitLab is really out of date.
The version 11.0 documentation was not any clearer about the differences between the online and active statuses.
